# Unable to connect to my GPUs using the VM

Tags: drivers, virtualization, vmware

The nvidia driver was working perfectly on my VMWare virtual machine, but suddenly and after some tensorflow and cuda installations, the driver failed to connect to the GPUs (I have two GPUs) , so I unistalled that driver (nvidia-driver-460) and tried literally every other available driver to fix the problem , tried to update the kernel , and even upgraded the system from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 but that did not work, so I wish anyone can help me discover and solve the problem …

When I run `nvidia-smi` I get this:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

And here are some diagnostical messages from the Kernal `dmesg | grep nvidia` :

```
[47841.841925] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered Nvlink Core, major device number 239
[47842.323471] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 239
[47842.325793] nvidia 0000:02:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=none,decodes=none:owns=none
               NVRM: specific graphics driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
[47842.326439] nvidia: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -1
[47842.327022] nvidia 0000:02:03.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=none,decodes=none:owns=none
               NVRM: specific graphics driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
[47842.327549] nvidia: probe of 0000:02:03.0 failed with error -1
[47842.327836] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered Nvlink Core, major device number 239
[47842.851441] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 239
[47842.853698] nvidia 0000:02:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=none,decodes=none:owns=none
               NVRM: specific graphics driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
[47842.854318] nvidia: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -1
[47842.854911] nvidia 0000:02:03.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=none,decodes=none:owns=none
               NVRM: specific graphics driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
[47842.855439] nvidia: probe of 0000:02:03.0 failed with error -1
[47842.855714] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered Nvlink Core, major device number 239
```

I tried installing other versions of nvidia drivers, and tried updating the system to ubuntu 22.04 , also tried to blacklist other drivers but nothing worked.